# css does not work in chrome (linux and windows)

Tags: windows, linux, firefox, css

i have this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
margin: 100px auto;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-right: 30px solid transparent;
border-top: 30px solid red;
border-left: 30px solid red;
border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
border-top-left-radius: 30px;
border-top-right-radius: 30px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
position: relative;
}
</style>
<div></div>
```

that produce:

[image: haflcircle]

in firefox,

but in chrome (linux, and windows - didnt try in mac) i see nothing why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe it is some sort of bug, actually. It works for me if you change the height and width to 1px. This leaves a little white dot, unfortunately, but that can be fixed by changing the background to red and the background-clip to content.

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/mb5jt/)

Comment: Looks like a bug. If you get rid of the border radius, it displays a triangle just fine.

Comment: I will add that the browser developers may argue this is NOT a bug.  I have run into this issue before and I concluded that in order to have a `border-radius` an element should arguably be at least 1px.  There is a mathematic method to how `border-radius` is calculated and rendered.  If a border-radius around something with height/width of 0 were permitted, then the mathematical calculation for rendering would be borked.

Comment: @Nate B - I suggest appending your answer with something similar to my comment so that future viewers of the question can understand a bit about why the zero value is not necessarily a bug (although one could argue either way).

Answer (score 1):

Because you gave 0px width and 0px height to the div so you see nothing.

```
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
```

Change this, hope it'll be visible.

Comment: Elements with a width and height of 0 are still visible (well, their borders are). I use them all the time for CSS arrows. This particular situation seems to be a rendering bug on Chrome's part.

Comment: Thanks but when I use a div with 0px of width and height and if that div contains nothing (no text or anything else inside it) then I see nothing.